Substitute a matching pair of single quotes with a matching pair of double quotes
I'm trying to develop a function in Go that scans through a string and replaces pairs of single quotes with pairs of double quotes. Specifically, I want to transform any single-quoted segments into double-quoted segments, while preserving other parts of the string.
Problem
Given the input string:
'Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"'
I want to achieve the following output:
"Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'"
However, the current implementation is giving me an incorrect output:
''"Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'"

package main

import (
    "strings"
    "fmt"
)

func transformQuotes(input string) string {
    var result strings.Builder
    inSingleQuote := false
    startIndex := 0

    for i, r := range input {
        switch r {
        case '\'':
            if inSingleQuote {
                // Closing a single-quoted section
                result.WriteString(`"`)
                innerContent := input[startIndex+1 : i]
                result.WriteString(strings.ReplaceAll(innerContent, `"`, `'`))
                result.WriteString(`"`)
                inSingleQuote = false
            } else {
                // Opening a single-quoted section
                inSingleQuote = true
                startIndex = i
                // Write any preceding characters up to the quote
                result.WriteString(input[:startIndex])
            }
        case '"':
            if inSingleQuote {
                // Inside single quotes, replace double quotes with single quotes
                result.WriteRune('\'')
            } else {
                // Outside of single quotes, keep double quotes as is
                result.WriteRune(r)
            }
        default:
            if !inSingleQuote {
                // Outside a single-quoted section, add the character to result
                result.WriteRune(r)
            }
        }
    }

    // Handle the case where there's an unmatched single quote at the end
    if inSingleQuote {
        result.WriteString(`'`)
        result.WriteString(input[startIndex+1:])
    }

    return result.String()
}

func main() {
    input := `'Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"'`
    fmt.Println(transformQuotes(input))
}



Issue:

The output includes extra single quotes at the beginning.
The transformation of quotes does not align with the desired output.

Question:
What modifications are needed to correctly transform single-quoted segments into double-quoted segments, and ensure that the other parts of the string remain unchanged?

What's up with all these conditions? Simply replace one type of quote with the other: https://go.dev/play/p/heatsA7ld-l

Perhaps I asked for help too quickly. I was able to figure it out.
Here is what I came up with:

func transformQuotes(input string) string {
    var result strings.Builder
    inSingleQuote := false
    startIndex := 0

    for i, r := range input {
        switch r {
        case '\'':
            if inSingleQuote {
                // Closing a single-quoted section
                result.WriteString(`"`)
                innerContent := input[startIndex+1 : i]
                // Replace inner double quotes with single quotes
                result.WriteString(strings.ReplaceAll(innerContent, `"`, `'`))
                result.WriteString(`"`)
                inSingleQuote = false
                startIndex = i + 1
            } else {
                // Opening a single-quoted section
                inSingleQuote = true
                // Add everything up to this point, not handled inside single quotes
                result.WriteString(input[startIndex:i])
                startIndex = i
            }
        }
    }

    // Append any remaining part of the string
    if startIndex < len(input) {
        result.WriteString(input[startIndex:])
    }

    return result.String()
}

If anyone has a more elegant solution, I will be happy to see that too.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
